# Python modules are not properly loaded fron Jenkins shell

Tags: shell, unit-testing, jenkins, conda, boto3

I have configured a conda environment and created python project. I am using Jenkins freestyle job for project testing. Activated a conda env from Jenkins shell and getting **modules not found** error, already installed all the required modules to this env.

For information testing cases are working properly when executing `pytest server/` command from terminal workspace.

Jenkins Shell Command

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/user/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate Unit-Test
pip list
pytest server/
```

Using `pip list` command I try to check the modules installed in env from terminal and Jenkins shell and found some of the libraries are missing when checked from Jenkins Shell.

Already checked with deleting the Jenkins Job caching and created new job to check, but issue still persists. Also tried to install the missing libraries again and again but still having the same issue.

Following libraries are missing in Jenkins shell: (Difference)

```
asttokens
backcall
debugpy
decorator
executing 
ipykernel
pickleshare
psutil
pure-eval
Pygments
python-dateutil
```

I am not using these libraries directly but **boto3** uses **python-dateutil** as support and I am getting the error:

```
import boto3
    from boto3.session import Session
    import botocore.session
    import botocore.client
    from botocore import waiter, xform_name
    from botocore.docs.docstring import WaiterDocstring
    from botocore.docs.service import ServiceDocumenter
    from botocore.docs.bcdoc.restdoc import DocumentStructure
    from botocore.compat import OrderedDict
    from dateutil.tz import tzlocal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil'
```

I did not get any reason for the issue.

Need Help, Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Why not install all the modules as part of the job run?

pip install -r requirements.txt

Define all requirements in requirements.txt.

Comment: Good point, but I think it will take more time, no issue I will give it a try, I have already checked with installing reasonable library. Thanks